# Static linking FFmpeg libraries on android

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ndk, static-libraries, static-linking, configure

I am trying to build **FFmpeg** for **android** as **static libraries** on a **MacOS** Sierra machine.

Following is my `buildscript.sh` which is very much based upon the one in [here](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/FFmpeg-Android/blob/master/build_ffmpeg_for_android.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ffmpeg-3.3.4

NDK=/path/to/android/ndk/android-ndk-r15c
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
CPREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld
RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
STRIP=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip
X264LIB=$X264/android/arm/lib/
X264INC=$X264/android/arm/include/

function build_ffmpeg_android {

./configure \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \
    --disable-stripping
    --arch=arm \
    --cpu=cortex-a8 \
    --target-os=linux \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --enable-pic \
    --disable-programs \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-shared \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --disable-doc \
    --enable-postproc \
    --enable-swscale \
    --enable-avfilter \
    --enable-avresample \
    --disable-opencl \
    --disable-securetransport \
    --enable-gpl \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS -I$X264INC"  \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS -s -L$X264LIB -lx264" \
    --enable-gpl \
    --enable-decoders \
    --enable-encoders \
    --enable-muxers \
    --enable-demuxers \
    --enable-parsers \
    --enable-protocols \
    --enable-filters \
    --enable-avresample \
    --enable-libfreetype \
    --disable-indevs \
    --enable-indev=lavfi \
    --disable-outdevs \
    --enable-hwaccels \
    --enable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --disable-network \
    --enable-libx264 \
    --enable-zlib \
    --enable-muxer=md5
    make clean
    make -j9
    make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_ffmpeg_android
```

The output of above script is placed inside `ffmpeg-3.3.4/android/arm`.

**My issue:**
When trying to link to these `.a` libraries from my app using `-lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -lavfilter -lswresample -lavdevice`,
I get the following **linker error** for each of them

```
:-1: error: error: avformat: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
:-1: error: error: avcodec: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
:-1: error: error: swscale: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
:-1: error: error: avutil: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
:-1: error: error: avfilter: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
:-1: error: error: swresample: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
:-1: error: error: avdevice: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
```

Looking at [this discussion here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/25032), I am doing it correct by selecting `arm-linux-androideabi-ar` in `CPREFIX`.

Trying to solve the error, I've also added the following configure flag for `ranlib` to be picked up specifically for android but doesn't seem to help.

```
RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
```

**My Questions:**

- What else am I missing here?
- **What is needed in my `buildscript.sh` to pick the correct ranlib & stop complaining about archive symbol table when linking from my app?**

Comment: CPREFIX should be `$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-`, no **`ar`**.

Comment: @AlexCohn is it ok to set `AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar` as one of the configure flags ?

Comment: @AlexCohn Updated my script again in the question. I have desperately been trying a lot of things. but unsuccessful with this error :( would be grateful if you please take a look at my script. please take a look. I have updated the **no ar** suggestion but still doesn't work. something still missing

Comment: now added a bounty to this question to get some attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following are the correct configure flags:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=$PREFIX \
  --disable-stripping \
  --arch=arm \
  --cpu=armv5te \
  --disable-asm \
  --target-os=linux \
  --enable-cross-compile \
  --enable-debug \
  --enable-pic \
  --disable-programs \
  --enable-static \
  --disable-shared \
  --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
  --disable-doc \
  --enable-postproc \
  --enable-swscale \
  --enable-avfilter \
  --enable-avresample \
  --disable-opencl \
  --disable-securetransport \
  --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
  --enable-videotoolbox \
  --enable-avresample \
  --disable-symver \
  --extra-cflags="-O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG-march=armv5te -mtune=arm9tdmi -msoft-float"
  $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
  make clean
  make -j9
  make install
```

**Note** that following cflags make the difference on android

```
--extra-cflags="-O3 -Wall -pipe -std=c99 -ffast-math -fstrict-aliasing -Werror=strict-aliasing -Wno-psabi -Wa,--noexecstack -DANDROID -DNDEBUG-march=armv5te -mtune=arm9tdmi -msoft-float"
```

Answer (score 1):

Spent a day trying to build ffmpeg with updated x265 for Android.

x265 successfully compiles into static library, but when its time to include it in ffmpeg, I'm getting error:

```
...aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: error: x265: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
C compiler test failed.
```

It is really hard to find any information about this error in the web and I've tried nearly everything.
But... in my case **all you have to do is to update your CMAKE version.**

```
cmake 3.20.5 is installed but outdated
==> Upgrading cmake
  3.20.5 -> 3.21.0
```

Before this I had cmake 3.10.2.4988404 and everything worked as expected, then Homebrew updated cmake as a dependency for some package and headache begun.
To sum up: 'stable' versions of cmake for ffmpeg+x265 are **3.10.2** and **3.21.0**